# How to change the security group of Amazon EKS worker nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I want to add a security group to the worker nodes of Amazon EKS.

It seems that I can change "Additional security group" to add the security group to the worker nodes.

[image]

But I cannot find any way to modify "Additional security group" in AWS console.

Does anyone know how to add security groups to the worker nodes?

Answer (score 2):

I can see two possible issues here:

- First of all, security groups can be assigned to EKS control plane only during creation. To add additional security groups you unfortunately have to re-create your cluster
- Second, the above won't help you, as this is only about the control plane. If you need to add more security groups to your worker nodes, you need to make modification on "compute" tab using launch templates